# What is `runfile` command in IPython?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, ipython

When running a file using console in Pycharm, I see on top of the console that Pycharm had simply executed this command in the console:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Alex/code/proj1/asset_management.py', wdir='C:/Users/Alex/code')
```

However, I find `runfile` is strange and seems to be unique to Pycharm console. Any more information on this?

BTW, I find it more powerful than Vscode which rule files like this

```
 & C:/Users/Alex/.conda/envs/ve/python.exe c:/Users/Alex/code/proj1/asset_management.py
```

without specifying working directory causing relative import errors. So, I'd love to be able to have access to `runfile` in a different IDE other than Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in the settings.json file:  `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,`